# Dynamically switching Google Maps API URL for users in China

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This question is not about why the coordinates within mainland China are incorrect. I already know that Chinese law is behind it with their secret algorithm, but more importantly, a Chinese server MUST be used to accurately plot map data within China.

According to google, their Chinese server is hosted at `maps.google.cn` whereas the rest of the world uses `maps.google.com` (notice the different TLD).

I would like to be able to embed a map using `.com` as the default and switch to `.cn` when viewing China. I could do a geolocation query to determine the browser location and load the relevant API, which would work well for users in China, but this doesn't work for users outside China (or those using a VPN) when they view the mainland.

As far as I know, it is impossible to load and use both APIs within the same document. If somebody knows how to overcome this, please post as an answer. The next best thing is to offer users a link, essentially reloading the page with the correct API.

So, my question. When viewing [Google maps in a browser](http://www.google.com/maps/), the bottom right of the map contains the google footer with their copyright and terms. Also, for me at least, there is a link to `maps.google.cn`. Yet, in my own code and every embedded example I have found online, it is not there. Changing the `region` and `language` passed in the URL has no effect.

How can I make this link appear in my own embedded maps? Or, is there another workaround to the "google in China" problem?

Comment: See also: [Is it OK to use the maps.google.cn API outside of China?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836079/is-it-ok-to-use-the-maps-google-cn-api-outside-of-china)

Answer (score 3):

One technique you may be able to use to achieve this is to load the Maps API dynamically using JavaScript.  Instead of hardcoding a `<script src="...">` tag in your website, you can construct one dynamically and perhaps change the URL based on the detected location of the user.

```
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initialize&key=<YOUR KEY HERE>';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Your code would be responsible for changing the `script.src` value to `http://maps.google.cn/...` when the user is in China.